# Data is not binding in summernote.js in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, summernote

Added bootstrap , jquery and summernote references in angularjs project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVXP6.png)

binding ng-model attribute but unable to bind value to the summernote.js

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.